# Mobile Deeplink

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm wondering if the following can be safely implemented: I want to send a deep-link though emails, to certain people, which contain user credentials in order to start an app and log in automatically. Is it possible to do so with one click? I mean download the app and then launch the login activity and start the login process?

Comment: yes possible. for that you need to send the data with the link. use https://branch.io/.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: this technically works, but we recommend NOT using Branch links for confidential data like this because of the slight possibility (~0.1%) of false positives. If you want to give it a try anyway, make use of our `match_guaranteed` parameter, and be prepared to handle the failure state if that returns NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you have following solutions :

> 1. Deeplinking (as you suggested)

If you follow this approach make sure that the URL(http://...) which you send also works with the mobile web. The reason is say you send a deeplink url in the email and android application is not installed in the user's device then your deeplink will launch the web browser and your web site will open up.

> 2. Google / Facebook login
>      For a hassle free experience you can provide user with Google Login functionality in your app. As soon as user launches the app they can just select google login and proceed.

I think you are looking for this:

https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-android-deep-linking-google-play-referrer

You can encrypt your login information and pass it "referrer" parameter and later get it in Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: But can I do it in one shot with deep-links? I mean if the user doesn't have the app installed it will redirect them to the store in order to install it, but the first time it will run will it still have the parameters send through the deep-link? Because I doubt that will happen, and the user will need to click again on the link in order to launch it with the right parameters so that the login can take place.

Comment: Updated by answer.

Comment: This approach is probably relatively safe *when it works*. The Google Play Referrer is unreliable, often delivered late, and not compatible with a lot of edge cases, so you should design around the reality that autologin will fail a good percentage of the time.